# Setting the FontSize of textbox via RadioButtons

Tags: javascript, html

> Javascript:      function makeStyle(x) {
>
> ```
>           var x = document.getElementById("styleText");
>
>           if(document.getElementById("xx-small").checked)
>           {       
>               x.style.fontSize = "xx-small";
>           }
>           else if(document.getElementById("medium").checked)
>           {   
>               x.style.fontSize = "medium";
>           }
>           else if(document.getElementById("xx-large").checked)
>           {
>               x.style.fontSize = "xx-large";
>           }
>
>       }
>       document.getElementById('styleText').addEventListener('change', makeStyle);
> ```

HTML:

6. Style the text data as indicated in the selected radio button.

```
<label>xx-small</label><input type="radio" id="xx-small" name="rb" value="xx-small"  /><br/>
<label>medium</label><input type="radio" id="medium" name="rb" value="medium" /><br/>
<label>xx-large</label><input type="radio" id="xx-large" name="rb" value="xx-large" /><br/>   
<input type="text" id="styleText" value = "Random Text " />
```

My question is.. I can't seems to get the radiobutton to work properly by changing the fontsize in textbox. So therefore, how would I be able to fix this problem?

I'm sure I did something wrong but I can't quite seems to see the error that I have made.

Answer (score 1):

you've set the listener for `#styleText` which doesn't appear to be a radiobutton. you should attach the same listener to all 3 radio button ids. also, inside of your handler, you are reading values from the same element regardless of what was changed `var x = document.getElementById("styleText");`

Comment: So basically, I have to add 3 more of this       document.getElementById('styleText').addEventListener('change', makeStyle); ? Just replace styleText with id of radio buttons?

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the event listener for `<input type="text" id="styleText" value = "Random Text " />`  and add three event listeners for radio buttons in your javascript code :

Javascript: //**Add following code within window.onload event**

```
window.onload=function()
  {
    document.getElementById('xx-small').addEventListener('change', makeStyle);
    document.getElementById('xx-large').addEventListener('change', makeStyle);
    document.getElementById('medium').addEventListener('change', makeStyle);
  };
```

Here is the [JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gNajN/).

Comment: Thanks but when I tried to copy it and replace my old code.. It would not work. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: You must be doing some mistake as it is working perfect in the demo .

Comment: Well, do I need to do something aside from removing the event listener for styleText?

Comment: No you just have to remove event listener for styleText and add three listeners for radio button , or you can just simply copy and paste all the HTML and Javascript from the JS Fiddle Demo.

Comment: Tried that and I used firebug to debug and I got this error: 
TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
document.getElementById('xx-small').addEventListener('change', makeStyle);

Comment: I have edited the code snippet above, add the listeners within in window.onload event , the error was beacause before loading the radio button browser finds it and throws error.